# Understanding .msg files in omnet++ and veins

Tags: omnet++, veins, inet, sumo

I am  really new to `Omnet++` and `Veins` .I find it really hard to progress through `Omnet++` and `Veins` even with all the documentations provided .**Right now I am stuck at how .msg files are generated and how messages are handled in veins** .Can someone please help me with some documentation/tutorials/pointers to really understand these concepts .It would really help me out a lot as I am trying to learn this on my own which as of now is a really daunting task for me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In OMNeT++ `.msg` files are not generated, they are created by a developer.
Let's assume that one need a message that contains two fields: destination address (an integer) and sequence number (an integer). Let's name this type `FooMessage`. One creates a new file called `FooMessage.msg` with the following content:

```
// FooMessage.msg
message FooMessage {
  int destAddress;
  int seqNumber;
}
```

During building of this project two new files are **automatically** created: `FooMessage_m.h` and `FooMessage_m.cc`. They contain C++ class for the message as well as all setters and getters methods.
To use them one should write in own C++ code something like that:

```
#include "FooMessage_m.h"

FooMessage *msg = new FooMessage("First message");
msg->setDestAddress(230);
msg->setSeqNumber(1);
```

[TicToc Tutorial](https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/part4/#44-defining-our-message-class) contains more advance example. Moreover, [OMNeT++ Simulation Manual, Section 6](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#cha:msg-def) describes process of message definition.

Comment: Thankyou very much for this answer .I was really stuck on this topic for a while and you have helped me in clarifying my doubts about this topic. Trying to learn this on my own has been a major challenge .Thanks again :)